# Google Plus image sharing issue

Tags: google-plus, facebook-opengraph, semantic-markup, schema.org

I want to have my post image to be fetched and displayed by google plus whenever someone posts my URL.

I'm a bit confused with all these opengraph/schema formats.

It's working fine on facebook and twitter and I can see the data correctly structured on the debugger tools (both [facebook's](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) and [google's](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=https%3A%2F%2Fverios.com.br%2Fblog%2Fate-quando-voce-quer-trabalhar%2F)).

Here's my [blog](https://verios.com.br/blog/) and a [sample post](https://verios.com.br/blog/ate-quando-voce-quer-trabalhar) and here's what my HTML looks like:

```
<head>
  ...
  <meta name="description" content="{{post.excerpt}}">
  <meta property="og:type" content="article">
  <meta property="og:url" content="{{post.permalink}}">
  <meta property="og:title" content="{{post.title}}">
  <meta property="og:description" content="{{post.excerpt}}">
  <meta property="og:image" content="{{post.image}}"> <!-- absolute path here -->
  <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
  <meta name="twitter:site" content="{{twitterProfile}}">
  <meta name="twitter:image:src" content="{{post.image}}"> <!-- absolute path here -->
  ...
</head>
<body>
  ...
  <article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
    <meta itemprop="inLanguage" content="pt-BR">
    <meta itemprop="inFamilyFriendly" content="True">
    <meta itemprop="image" content="{{post.image}}">  <!-- absolute path here -->
    <div class="post-hero">
      <section itemprop="associatedMedia" style="background-image: url({{post.image}});">
      </section> <!-- absolute path here -->
      <section>
        <h1 itemprop="headline name">
          <a itemprop="url" href="{{post.permalink}}" title="{{post.title}}">{{post.title}}</a>
        </h1>
        ...
      </section>
      ...
    </div>
    ...
  </article>
  ...
</body>
```

Am I missing something? Should I move my Article Scope to the HTML tag? If so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was a caching problem. 
I appended a query string to the URL and the image got pulled up.

Comment: Thanks :)
"You can accept your own answer tomorrow"